# Simple Question about Javascipt | I want to learn an item in an example code

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

```
($("element").data('bs.modal') || {}).isShown
```

I found this code.People says it checks bootstap modal is open.So, what is meaning of "element"? Is it id of modal div?

How can I write a simple function for this in Javascript:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg" data-whatever="@mdo" id="deneme1" style="z-index: 2147483647;"><i class="fa fa-edit text-thm2"></i> Sign Up</a>
                            <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
```

If above modal is open, set mininmum z-index value for

```
<div  id="sticky-header-navbar">
```

If modal is close, again set max value for #sticky-header-navbar

I wait your helps.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery function `$()` [will match elements in a page](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) if you pass it a CSS selector

The [css selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) `element` matches the tag `<element>`

So, if you want to select all `<div>`s in your page, you could use `$("div")`. You can use more complicated css selectors too, `$('.myClass')` will match all HTML tags with `class="myClass"`.